# accessing super class in java

Tags: java

Am I using the superclass correctly to access the `title`, `minutes` and `price`?

```
 public class Video extends CollectionItem
    {

      public Video(String title, 
          int minutes, double price) {

    super(title,minutes,price);

      }

      public String getTitle() {
        return super(title);
      }

      public int getMinutes() {
        return super(minutes);
      }

      public double getPrice() {
        return super(price);
      }

      public double pricePerMinute() {
        return 
            super(price)/super(minutes);
      }

}
```

here is my superclass can you check to make sure i did everything correctly i am very new to this and i did research i just thought that super() was the correct way

```
Public class CollectionItem
{

  public String title;
    public int minutes;
    public double price;
    public int pages;


public Video(String title, 
      int minutes, double price) {

    this.title = title;
    this.minutes = minutes;
    this.price = price;
  }


public Book(String title, 
      int pages, double price) {

    this.title = title;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.price = price;
  }


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public int getPages() {
    return pages;
  }

  public double getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public int getMinutes() {
    return minutes;
  }


}
```

Comment: I downvoted this question because it shows no research effort.

Comment: @Robin Green Have you ever been a newbie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're not.

It depends on how the super class is defined. If the price,minutes fields are defined as protected then you access them just by writing their name. So,

```
public int getPrice() { 
  return price;
}
```

Even more likely, is that the super class defines a public getter method such as:

```
public int getPrice() {
  return price;
}
```

If that is the case, then there's no need to define a similar method in the subclass since the method from the super class is inherited by the subclass.

Comment: could you look at my superclass, i keept getting a invlaid declaration method at public Video(String title, int minutes, double price){

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not the right way to use super. Try

```
public class Video extends CollectionItem {

  public Video(String title, 
      int minutes, double price) {

    super(title,minutes,price);

  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return super.getTitle();
  }

  ...

}
```

I am assuming i) that `CollectionItem` defines a `getTitle()` method and ii) that `CollectionItem` stores the value passed in the constructor.

In this case, it is would not be necessary to override `getTitle()` in the `Video` class too. You could rely on the one defined in `CollectionItem` only with `this.getTitle()`.

If title was made protected in the `CollectionItem`, you could get the title with `super.title;` instead.

Answer (score 3):

In general you use `super` the same way you'd use `this`. So to access something in the superclass called "foo" you say `super.foo`. The only time you say `super(...)` is when invoking a constructor (and just like the `this(...)` syntax this is only possible as the first statement in a constructor).